# Why is the title included in the URL of questions?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

Here's the URL of a recently asked question on SO:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005768/specifying-a-pronunciation-of-a-word-in-microsoft-speech-api
```

Why is the title of the question included in the URL?  It's not needed to access it.  The number will suffice:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005768
```

Is it just for the sake of human readability on mouse-overs?

Comment: Just to be sure you know: *anything* is accepted [as the title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68401/do-not-click-me) and redirects just fine to the current URL. (Which, of course is required, as titles could change.)

Answer (score 19):

Forget SEO, who cares about that!

What does this link to?

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345`

What does this link to?

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345/ponies-and-unicorns`

It seems to me that one is much clearer than the other, and preferable in all circumstances except in the case where you need an artifically short link. Which we also support, as:

`http://stackoverflow.com/q/12345`

Comment: I didn't know about the shortcut option... where did this was documented?

Comment: So, it is just for the sake of human readability?

Comment: the short link is not only good for being short, it's also good when you only have the article number (e.g. from the [reputation report](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation()

Comment: raven: human readability is a _very_ just sake.

Comment: @stacker short links are documented at http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/ and http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/

Comment: Very true, and yet another reason why I dislike [the hidden referral links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74274/privacy-leak-in-permalink) for questions, which are easily used by accident!

Comment: @arjan hidden in plain sight! We are so sneaky...

Comment: Either that, @Jeff, or there are [300 users](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/69083/usage-of-se-referrals) who willingly post annoying non-self-describing links on SO itself? (As an aside: it's [Data Privacy Day](http://dataprivacyday2011.org/) tomorrow!)

Comment: @arjan remember that `link` did not exist on questions until this though -- the only way to get a question link was off the `<h1>` on the page

Comment: @Jeff, I'm not sure if that helps your statement about being sneaky or not. Are you trying to say that before August 2010, many of us were used to copying the `<h1>` or the location bar itself, and are probably still doing so? But *new* users might not be aware that the `<h1>` is clickable, and might simply see that `link` and use that instead? (Also: so that's already 300 users since August 2010?)

Answer (score 8):

Because of **Search Engine Optimization**, you can read a bit more about it in [Googles Search Engine Optimization Guidelines](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35291)

Comment: I still don't get it.  Isn't it the *content* of the page that's important?  What difference does the *address* make?

Comment: @raven the address also plays a part when search engines measure the relevance of a URL for a search term. Not as much as the content, of course, but it's still relevant.

Comment: I perused those pages but didn't see anything related to "URL optimization".  Is there a page I missed that specifically discusses how to craft one's URLs?

Comment: @raven, There's a document from Google about Search Enginge Optimization where it says a lot about URL structure. Can't find the PDF at the moment. But here's another resource for SEO and URL Structure: http://www.clickz.com/clickz/column/1712981/seo-url-structure

Comment: @Filip the word is engine, not enginge

Comment: @Dan, it's common that other people correct such mistakes when found. It's a simple typo.

Comment: @Filip - only if they have enough rep though. (Dan has less than 2K as of this writing).

Comment: I cannot edit your answers or comments, and I thought maybe you thought the word was enginge, as you wrote it 3 times.

Comment: Don't know why I wrote that three times, I guess I just copied the sentance. :)