# Privacy leak in permalink?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, privacy, sharing, permalink

## Update (Jan 8, 2019)

This is now 8 years old, but still getting occasional upvotes/attention, so I thought it's worth giving a summary of the current state.  Despite originally being [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), over the last decade some changes have made the privacy implications much clearer.  You now click "share" instead of "link", and the pop-up is very explicit that the link includes your user ID.

There is a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340346/anonymize-or-hash-the-user-id-part-of-a-shared-link-so-that-users-can-earn-badge) asking that this user ID be anonymized or hashed, to allow users to earn publicity badges (the intention behind having the user ID present in the URL, as per [Jeff's reason for declining this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74305/377214)) while eliminating the privacy issue.

## Original Post

It seems to me there is something of a privacy leak when permalinking to a question.  For what I would assume is the purposes of tracking which user is responsible for bringing traffic back to an SE site (for badges, etc.), the user ID of the user obtaining the permanent link [is included in the permanent link itself](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/).

I wouldn't argue that this shouldn't be the case, but I find no warning or mention of this when I do these actions.  I'm sure I'm not the only one that doesn't desire anonymity on SO but would like at least pseudonymity on some places I might share a SO link, such as on a random blog.

[image: Tooltip as shown when hovering the "link"]

As a user, I would not expect sharing a permanent link to leak my identity.   Unless you are familiar with Stack Exchange links or your own userID, it's certainly not obvious by looking at the link that it includes your personal info.  It'd be nice to have fair warning that using that feature will do so, and perhaps provide/describe the workaround: to simply remove the user-id segment from the URL.  Other features would be a preference that formats future permanent links to exclude the user id.

### Example (from this question)

- Permalink: [`https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74274/151280`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74274/151280)
- Link to my user page: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/151280

Comment: Your assumption is correct - the permalink is explicitly designed to contain your ID for the purposes of the badges like Announcer (and maybe other tracking). Answers don't have this, though, and as a workaround you can always use the question's title - it's a URL that does not feature your ID.

Comment: Or you could edit the link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74274

Comment: Definitely.  @JJnguy's workaround is what I was hinting at in my question.  I know workarounds already exist; my fear is that people won't even discover the privacy implications involved until it's "too late."  I don't know, maybe it's just something the community at large isn't too concerned about.

Comment: @Mark: Just FYI in case you didn't know, there are things in your profile that only you can see (okay, devs and moderators can see it too, but that's a tiny group of people).  Your email address and OpenID info remain hidden to everyone else.  Linking to that page shouldn't be a privacy concern.

Comment: @Bill: You're missing the point.  I'm not worried about that stuff being public.  I know what is public in my profile and I'm fine with that.  The point is, the user-id in the link could be an unintended way of publishing your identity in some context where you where aiming to have pseudonymity.

Comment: I generally get the permalink by right-clicking the question title instead of using the link button.

Comment: @Mark: I understand the point.  I was just commenting in case you were worried about those extra bits of info getting out.

Comment: As an aside: this has been in place [since August 2010](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/) or earlier.

Comment: IMHO, complaining about privacy on SO is... what can I say... dumb? Honestly, just delete your id if you complain so much about it. But if this feature is gone then I will start to complain.

Comment: As I quite often see these links used in comments, I *guess* many people indeed don't know about this. (If they would know: why not use the full links, so one knows [what the link refers to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) without clicking? I sometimes make the same mistake, but seeing no warning at all, I really doubt many know.)

Comment: @Arjan Why does it matter? SO is public, there is no private settings and it shall never have.

Comment: Because of the 2nd paragraph of the question, @Bruno.

Comment: This also applies to the *"Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, twitter, or facebook."* links (only appears [when there are no answers yet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54184/idea-to-promote-more-traffic-to-non-technical-related-stack-exchange-sites/72563#72563)). Though there sharing is non-anonymous by definition, it still might unexpectedly link accounts.

Comment: Some counting: since August/September 2010, about [300 SO users](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/69111/usage-of-se-referrals) *(accidentally?)* used the short referral links on SO itself. (This does [not count](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/) towards getting an Announcer, Booster or Publicist badge, so no benefits from that referral. But as such referral links lack the descriptive title —and hence need clicking to see what one is referring to— my *guess* is that folks would have posted the full link if they were aware of this.)

Comment: Related: [Does the button to share a question on Twitter use a link that allows to identify who shared the link?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88204/does-the-button-to-share-a-question-on-twitter-use-a-link-that-allows-to-identify)

Comment: my unrequested $0.05 worth ~ I totally don't get this question. The URL is present in the browser bar. You have to click something to get the question anyways. Every browser I recall has a deal where if you right click on the bar it will automatically highlight the text if you haven't focused it before. That's just as simple as right clicking the link. Same for the question title. Anyone who has used the site for long enough to be worried about it is going to know that's a referral link.

Comment: +1. User privacy matters. It's a big deal.

Comment: Now also [for answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63841/show-a-short-link-for-answers-too-not-just-questions). (And, @jcolebrand, no easily accessible way to get the full URL there, *if* one is aware of the tracking to start with.)

Comment: As mentioned on MathOverflow Meta, identity of a reviewer of a scientific paper was leaked in this way: [Privacy of software-generated links to questions and answers](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2167). At least making it more clear to the users who copy that link that it includes userid would be an improvement. (IMO it would be entirely satisfactory solution.)

Comment: @Martin RE your bounty reason: this is already easy to notice; for a while now, the share popup includes a prompt that the link includes one's user ID. There are still ways to end up with such links without being prompted, however, such as right-clicking the Share button and using the browser's option to copy the link. You might be interested in this feature request: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340346/anonymize-or-hash-the-user-id-part-of-a-shared-link-so-that-users-can-earn-badge

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog I somehow missed this. I am pretty sure this wasn't always the case. Do you happen to know when this was implemented? (As far as the linked question goes, I posted a bounty there to attract attention not too long ago.)

Comment: After nearly a decade of use, I've only just now noticed that links include the user ID. This is bad as it can lead to an anonymous Stack Exchange user to be doxxed if they copy & paste the link in an open-source project. Someone who `blame`s the link in an open-source project can then identify that Stack Exchange user.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Another option is to change the text from "link" to "referral link" when someone is logged in, so they are aware that it's a referral link.  If they don't want a referral link and deleting their userid is simply too much trouble, they only need to right click the post title and copy the URL.

This should resolve the problem:

- It alerts users that this link is a referral link, and may contain user specific information
- There is another link on the page already which does not contain that information

Most people who regularly share links are used to getting links from the title of blog posts, and those who care about being able to use a sanitized link will either figure it out, or ask on meta.

The majority of SO users won't care, but they will at least be alerted via the use of the word "referral".

Further, since the code already exists to differentiate between a logged in and not logged in user (ie, the link is created with a uid or not) then the code to change to a referral link is minimal.

Comment: I like [that](http://i.imgur.com/MoAva.png)!

Comment: I like this option.  After all, it wasn't the fact that it's a referral link that bothered me, but rather that there was very little transparency that it **was** a referral link.

Comment: As an aside: the same referral links are used in the *"Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, twitter, or facebook."* links (only appears [when there are no answers yet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54184/idea-to-promote-more-traffic-to-non-technical-related-stack-exchange-sites/72563#72563)). It's a bit harder to change the text there, I guess. Well, *Share a referral link* might do, of course!

Comment: I'm not sure, "referral link" is clear enough, you just see "link" and use it. It's a good idea, but there should be some warning on the first use, anyway. I'd prefer an anonymous link as the default with the possibility to change it to referral link for those who like it.

Answer (score 47):

I agree that the current behaviour is surprising. One would expect a clean link behind a "link" button, not a referral.

I suggest adding a second, anonymous linking option:

```
link · link (anonymous) · edit · close · flag
```

this is trivial to implement, makes the user aware of the issue, and gives them all the options they need.

Answer (score 34):

[Since March 2011](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4287/whats-a-good-ui-for-sharing-permalinks/4288#4288), clicking "link" now always shows a popup (while right-clicking still makes most browsers show something like "Copy link address"):

[image: The share a link popup after clicking it. How does that work in screen readers...?]

The text is different for questions and answers:

> share a link to this question
>   share a link to this answer

Would it be feasible to just change this, *when logged in*? Like:

> share a referral link to this question
>   share a referral link to this answer

Or even one better, to allow [easy access to the full URL for answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114088/can-we-please-have-an-easy-way-to-get-the-full-url-to-an-answer) too, some nifty way to toggle the type of URL? For both questions and answers:

[image: toggle anonymous and full url]

Likewise, with a different wording based on the link that is currently shown:

[image: Link options]
[image: Link options]
[image: Link options]

(The tooltips are still *"short permalink to this question"* and *"short permalink to this answer"*. When logged in, changing these to read *"short referral link to ..."* would be great too! And adding *"referral"* to the *"Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, twitter, or facebook."* [message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54184/idea-to-promote-more-traffic-to-non-technical-related-stack-exchange-sites/72563#72563) as well, would lower the chance of accidental referrals even more: though on social networks sharing is non-anonymous by definition, that link might unexpectedly associate accounts as well.)

Answer (score 18):

I also felt annoyed by the presence of the user ID on the short permalinks — not so much due to the privacy issue, but simply because I mostly use those links within the SE network, where the user ID is useless (you don't get badges for sharing links inside the network) and just wastes characters.

As a result, I added something vaguely similar to [Arjan's suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86835) into the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch (SOUP)](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) user script.  Instead of toggle links, however, my fix simply adds a second ID-less version of the URL into the share popup, like this:

> [image: Screenshot]

The URL with the user ID is still selected by default (because SOUP doesn't do anything about that), but if you prefer to use the anonymous URL, you can simply press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move the focus into the second textbox before copying its content with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

This change does make the popup a bit bigger, but I haven't observed any problems with it in practice.  The fix has been in the SOUP development branch for almost a year, and is now included in the just released stable version 1.46.

Comment: Actually since the switch to https, the badge is granted for internal links as well.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: That [does indeed seem to be the case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295575), although I suspect that's a bug. At least I've seen no indication that it would be intentional.

Comment: It's something technical: as far as I know, when using https, the referer header is not being sent or can't be used anymore, and the check for internal link (at least for that badge) depends on this header as there is no query string info where the user came from.

Comment: Well, in that case let's hope the team will fix this, though being minor bug the chances are very low.

Comment: FYI: Yesterday's update to SE's HTML has resulted in the SOUP fix for this no longer working.

Comment: I would also suggest to increase this popup's width just a little bit so that the urls fit completely without the need for horizontal scroll.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMaskV2, does bug reported that internal links are counted? Or  it was  intentional change? In current badge description  https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/75/booster there is not mentioned , that they applicable for external links only

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim yes, see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134185/publicity-badges-might-be-taking-internal-links-into-account). You can start a feature request to change the badge description to match the actual behavior, yeah.

Comment: Although I like the idea of referral URL for badges and stimulating the growth of smaller sites, this is the best option: Offer a referral and anonymous URL when 'share' is clicked.

Answer (score 13):

If this feature request gets enough upvotes (ie, a lot of people are concerned about it, and want it changed) then one way to implement this is to add a user-preference in the user account screen which disables the userID on links.  It seems to me that those who would be concerned about this would want to set it and forget it.

Comment: But I doubt many people are that interested...

Comment: Yes, that's what I was getting at with the last sentence in the question.  But from my perspective it's not the hassle of anonymizing the link, it's just the fact that nowhere are you warned that you ARE leaking your user id.

Comment: If we did that, then we'd have to disable it by default, or we'd also be accused of Zuckerpunching people in the Atwood, or Spolsky, whichever sounds more anitomical.

Comment: An easier implementation would be to add the message on the `title` of the link. I wouldn't like to see privacy settings on SO. But this message is ok if it shut up this stupid request (IMO)

Comment: It should be opposite way - privacy by default!

Answer (score 9):

This is implemented to support the Booster, Promoter, and Publicist badges:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/

You can always just delete the user ID from the shortened URL -- it will still work.

Additionally if you browse in incognito (anonymous) mode the URLs do not contain the userid, since obviously you have no user id from the site's perspective -- you're not logged in!

Comment: That's a relevant point about incognito mode, although most privacy mode that browsers provide still enable cookies (they just don't carry over from the normal session and they are deleted at the end of the session) so it doesn't prevent you from logging in.  Anyway the point wasn't about not having a workaround, it was the fact that it is completely hidden to a casual user that the user id *is* leaked.  I'd just settle for a warning or even the link being something like `http://stackoverflow.com/q/#####/####/mark-peters` where it's obvious.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't envision scenarios where it would be so critical to be in incognito mode anyway.  I'm not talking about high-risk spying in general.  One simple example is just some blog where I'd rather remain anonymous.  Like `thedailywtf.com`.  I trust the community here to not do dumb stuff after finding out some basic information about me more than I do on that site.

Comment: @Mark, I'd rather not include the display name: currently, changing that name does not change it on the many copy cat websites that republish the SOFU content. Adding the display name to the links as well makes it even slightly harder to change one's name at some later time, after one has posted it somewhere.

Comment: Hey @Jeff, can you comment on why this has been declined?  Not enough interest?  Privacy isn't a concern here?  I only ask because it seems in your answer above that you think somebody was suggesting that the user id **shouldn't** be in the link.  We weren't saying that; we were just asking for a little more transparency/warning that it was a referral.  If it's declined I wouldn't mind knowing that the powers at be actually understood both the problem and the request.

Comment: This is so wrong. A permalink should not contain user information. It should point to the content and nothing more. With this kind of links a user is traceable all over the internet. I prefer privacy over badges but do you prefer privacy over site traffic?

Answer (score 5):

...or at least use a query parameter, like `http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74274?user=151280` to make clear(er) what's going on. Yes, that's a few more characters.

<sup><sup>And no, please do not also add it to full URLs then...</sup></sup>

Comment: Good idea, but I think it is a technical matter of URL Rewriting, not sure it's possible with querystrings, at least not with a major tweak.

Comment: The current URLs redirect to ones without the user id (but with the full slug), so the statistics are handled during the redirect/rewriting. Easily done using query parameters as well, @ShadowWizard.

Answer (score 4):

[Stackapps SOX](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox) has this feature as "Remove your user ID from the 'share' link"

Answer (score -5):

I don't see how this is a problem.

Your Stack Overflow profile is not private.  And the post that you are linking to is not private.  And it is clear that you are associating yourself with the link that you post when you post it.

I'm not sure what privacy is lost by placing the user id in the URL.

Comment: Why is it clear that you are associating yourself with the link that you post when you post it?  What if you're just sharing a link to something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books.  Not only are there so many users there that they'd never be able to guess who you (the link-sharer) are by looking at the thread, there is really no reason to believe you are associated with that question.  You could just think it's a cool thing to pass on.  And by doing so, you've ruined any pseudonymity you had where ever you posted it.

Comment: @Mark, I guess I assume that whoever you share a link with would make the connection between you the link poster and you on stackoverflow.  I know they would for me for sure.

Comment: Ok let me describe a hypothetical scenario.  Say I was an active member of a mutually anonymous group that published opposition opinion pieces in some dictatorship without freedom of speech.  I survive only by nobody knowing my true identity there.  In parallel, in my normal life, I am a software professional with a StackOverflow account asking questions and giving answers in a safe way that doesn't belie my "secret" behaviour.  One day, somebody on this site asks me a technical question.  I find the answer on a StackOverflow question and post it.  Boom, all my pseudonymity is gone; I'm dead.

Comment: @Mark, i'm sorry to hear of your plight, but that is totally unrealistic.  And, if you were leading a double life, you would be much more careful about everything you did.

Comment: @JJnguy: It's not my plight.  It was just a scenario to demonstrate the issue because you were missing it.  It's not entirely unrealistic, but in reality it'd be more like something like "I want to remain anonymous on Reddit but reveal my true identity on StackOverflow".  If I naively post a permalink to Reddit I've leaked my user id.

Comment: @Justin: It's not AT ALL unrealistic. It's exactly how dissidents get discovered and killed.

Comment: @NicholasKnight Do you have a real-world example?  With a contrived example, one can prove anything.

Comment: Here's my scenario: After 15 years in Usenet under my real name, I have found enough reasons to keep my true identity completely separate from my SO identity, and I'd do a lot to keep it that way. So far, there is no publicly available link between the two. However, should I ever publish such a link under my true identity, this separation would break down. Note that it is completely irrelevant whether I am an endangered dissidents or what else my reasons for this are — just be assured that I would consider completely wiping out this 60k+ account if it got compromised.

Comment: Here’s four people who have been materially affected by a breakdown in the separation of their online and offline lives: [a gamer](http://theverge.com/e/5839220), [a journalist](http://t.co/qC5hIYuW), [a security researcher](http://t.co/75p2ER590z), and [a divorcée](http://gu.com/p/2fx3q/sbl). Not to mention [scores of victims of harassment](http://nyti.ms/1OdUofU), employees with [intrusive bosses](http://bit.ly/14OcMTf), women who are [denigrated](http://wrd.cm/1oveg1s) once their gender becomes known, and so on. The consequences don’t have to be life and death for privacy to be important.