# Does Facebook sharing work correctly for Stack Overflow questions?

Tags: support, facebook

When I click on [the Facebook link](http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https://stackoverflow.com/q/5262039/213725&t=SSIS+Term+Extraction+for+non-English+text)  for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262039/ssis-term-extraction-for-non-english-text) it gives a link like this:

```
http://http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fq%2F5262039%2F213725/
```

Does anybody experience a similar problem?

Comment: Note that the last `213725` [is your user id](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74274/privacy-leak-in-permalink).

Answer (score 3):

This is simply the encoded URL in the Facebook sharing querystring.

`http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fq%2f5608131%2f1&t=Wijmo+Dialog+Feature+visible+problems`

In the actual sharing on Facebook it will be correct:

[image]

Comment: isn't this about **the double** `http` in `http://http%3A%2F%2F`, that apparently shows after clicking [that link](http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://stackoverflow.com/q/5262039/213725&t=SSIS+Term+Extraction+for+non-English+text)? (Still then, I guess that is a Facebook error then, **unless** FB wants the links without the `http://` prefix, or unless FB does not recognize the encoded `%3A%2F%2F` and then prefixes `http://` itself? I'm not using FB, so cannot test.)

Comment: (If FB does —or did— not recognize the `%3A%2F%2F` then that is their fault too, of course.)