# Does the button to share a question on Twitter use a link that allows to identify who shared the link?

Tags: support, share-this

When on an SE site I use the button to the left of a question to share a link to the question on Twitter, am using a Twitter message that contains a code that identifies who shared the link?

I used the link added to the Twitter messages generated by that link, but it seems that the link goes directly to the question page.

Is there any difference between the link produced by the "share link" button, and the link obtained from the "link" button on the bottom of the question?
As far as I can see, that link contains my user ID on the site.

**Update**: I am not concerned about the privacy. If I would want to share the link to a question without it contains any data that identify me, then I would use the link I see in the address bar of the browser.
I am asking the question to understand if SE knows I am sharing links to SE questions when I am using the "share on Twitter" button.

Comment: Related: [Privacy leak in permalink?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74274/privacy-leak-in-permalink)

Comment: My concern is not the privacy; it is rather the opposite, as I was interested to know which link I should use to let SE know I am sharing SE links.

Comment: Okay! Still, the fact you have to ask rings alarm bells for me. It should be clear to whoever is using this, in my opinion.

Comment: @Arjan I have to ask because the link to the question that appears in the twitter is shortened, and I am redirected to the question when I use that link. I don't see my user ID being used, when I look at the URL shown from the browser.

Comment: I understand, @kiamlaluno, and I am glad *you* were not surprised by the hidden user id. But, your question aside: the fact that you were *expecting* it, but still could not find it, makes me worry about others who are *not* expecting it, and are not even looking for it... :-(

Comment: (And, @kiamlaluno, phwd's answer is a "Yes". So I guess that's your answer.)

Comment: @Arjan I got it. Whenever I don't want my ID to appear, or I want it appears, the fact I am asking means it is not clearly stated the shared links contain the user ID. I apologize; sometimes I am slow to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the same, it is shortened by t.co
To reassure yourself view the source and look for the script right before the share button.

Also if you do use the "link" button it redirects as well.

Example : Web Applications (40 is my userid)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var shareUrl = "http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/14686/40";
            var shareMsg = "Stack Exchange Web Applications Q: Change the default RSS reader of Google Chrome?";
            StackExchange.share.facebook($('#fb-share14686'), shareUrl, shareMsg);
            StackExchange.share.twitter($('#twitter-share14686'), shareUrl, shareMsg);
        });
    </script>
```