# Is it possible to see how many people you've refered to a question or answer? (And if not, can it be made possible, please?)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, referrals

Now that you get badges for referrals... is it possible to see how well you're doing on those badges (e.g. by seeing the number of referrals in the past three days, and all time?)

If not, can we have that feature?

Comment: Not possible right now, far as I know.

Answer (score 8):

I do this by using a url-shortening service like Google's [goo.gl](http://goo.gl) and sharing that link. I'm sure other URL shorteners do this, but goo.gl allows you to see the number of clicks in the past two hours / day / week.

Comment: I'd like to see the engine's numbers though, as those are what's used for badge calculations.

Comment: Of course this could be circumvented if people check the links (using a link expander) prior to following them.  I will _ALWAYS_ check links before I ever consider following such links and use the discovered link.  So it won't be very effective for tracking cautious people such as myself.

Comment: @Brock: Huh? A shortened link just redirects to the real one, which has your User Id in it (which I believe is how StackOverflow knows it's *your* link). I don't see why it wouldn't count as a visit.

Comment: It's probably something like: (A) Page requested with a SO referring page = counts.  (B) Page requested with goo.gl as referrer = doesn't count. ... Try inserting a goo.gl link and seeing if it shows in the sidebar as a linked post. ... Also, where do referring links have any user ID?  See the referring link in the first comment of [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97716/148310), for example.

Comment: @Brock: A link does not always have a user Id in it. If you closely look at the Url given by the `link` links on questions and answers you'll see your User Id. Like the one you just linked, for example. I bet your user Id is `148310`. I don't think it's any more complicated than that. Why would it be?

Comment: It better not be like that!  If it is, a lot of us aren't getting credit for referrals.  That link had my user id because I grabbed it from the ***link*** tool.  I (and I suspect a huge number of others) don't always do that.  See, for example, the main link (cited earlier) that referred to this page.  And, it was posted by a power user.

Comment: This blog post http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/, as well as the first comment on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74274/privacy-leak-in-permalink. How else would you be awarded the badges? How would StackOverflow know that *you* were the one who referred the link?

Comment: Well it appears you are right and SO did what was easy, not what was right.   Now, not only do oodles of us share links that we don't get credit for, but users are not warned that the links share PII when posted on 3rd party websites!!! **Not** acceptable.  But, your answer is plausible, for now.

Comment: @Brock: I agree; You could open another question to get some more information about it.

Comment: Looks like it's already been discussed and a fix declined.  Not much more to do until the class-action. ;)