# Display statistics for question and answer referrals

Tags: feature-request, referrals

There are appears to be no area on the site to see the referral statistic.

It would be nice if there was a tab on the user profile that allowed me to see a list of links I shared with the referral counts, this would allow me to both track what it is I shared, and my progress towards the various sharing badges ([announcer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/74/announcer), [booster](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/75/booster), [publicist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/76/publicist))

Comment: Related:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93839.  Not entirely/truly a dupe though.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/bbwqzmmo/1/

[image: [========---------------------]]

A progress indicator, less sucky than those in review.