# View analytics for referral links

Tags: feature-request, publicity-badges, referrals, analytics

Clicking the link button brings up a text box with a referral link of the form `/q/[post ID]/[user ID]`.  The presence of the user ID in this link allows the system to track the number of visits due to this link and award the [announcer, booster, and publicist badges](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/).

This is a nice system.  It's nicer than using a bit.ly, goo.gl or other tracking-enabled URL shorteners because the links aren't obfuscated.  However, this tracking is wasted on awarding these three badges just once for each user.

I propose that navigating to a tracking URL, if logged in with the `[user ID]` in the URL, should display analytics for that link to the user who created it.  This would not only be useful when auditing one's progress towards the badge, but more importantly, **it would be very helpful when doing community evangelism.**

Comment: Related [Is it possible to see how many people you've refered to a question or answer? (And if not, can it be made possible, please?)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93839) (in less-elaborated form)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display statistics for question and answer referrals](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97716/display-statistics-for-question-and-answer-referrals)

Comment: Both of those linked questions request this functionality only for the purposes of badge tracking, which isn't very important.  This proposal is about using these analytics for better community evangelism.

Comment: How does one answer this question...

Comment: @Gabe - You won't be able to answer this question.  The team will be able to answer it, by tagging and answering **[status-completed]** - *Stats are now posted at `/q/[post ID]/[user ID]/tracking`*, **[status-planned]** - *We're thinking about it, but we're not sure about X, we've started a question about X and once that's resolved we'll proceed with this*, **[status-declined]** - *We don't want to do this because of Y, and the community probably can't change our minds*, or **[status-deferred]** - *We're working on more important stuff now, give us some time.*

Comment: @KevinVermeer Oh, thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: @Gabe - The bounty is based on [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/56044), where Jeff states that he tries to answer featured questions

Comment: As the [history](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/108738/revisions) shows, there was a bounty worth 200 reputation by Jeremy Banks starting December 3rd.  It's now expired with no activity.