# Can there be way to see details on where all the visitors to my question are coming from?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, permalink

I know there are badges for X number of times a question is viewed via a personal link to it.

Is there any way (with the data explorer or something else) to view all of the referring pages for all of my questions?
That way I can see who/from where all the views are coming from on my questions.

---

#### Update

This has been changed to a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request):

Can we have a way to view all of the referring sites that have a permalink to our own questions?

#### Explanation:

The request would be to be able to view ***how many*** *and* ***where*** people are coming from via question links.
Whether it is:

- From the Stack Overflow Main page
- From Stack Chat
- From another Stack post
- From an external site
- The list goes on...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to see how many people you've refered to a question or answer? (And if not, can it be made possible, please?)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93839/is-it-possible-to-see-how-many-people-youve-refered-to-a-question-or-answer-a), [View analytics for referral links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108738/view-analytics-for-referral-links), [Display statistics for question and answer referrals](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97716/display-statistics-for-question-and-answer-referrals)

Comment: @CodyGray That is not the same at all. I am requestion where the links are from. **not** how many. Also, the 2nd link -- I am requesting for the Question asker, not the link creator.

Comment: @CodyGray all of those links have to do with the sharer, not the one who has written the question...

Comment: @shog9 -- see above comments. those are **not** duplicates because those are referring to the one who created the link ***not*** the one who *was* linked...

Comment: Ah, sorry - forgot to edit out the other links. The top one was / is the one you're looking for.

Comment: @Shog9 my request has **nothing** to do with linkbacks at all!

Comment: How is what you're asking for different?

Comment: I am asking if there is a way to track where and how many people are coming ***from*** the links. I dont care how many links there are out there.

Comment: You already have that. It's called 'views' - it shows up to the right of every question.

Comment: @Shog9 yes, but if I suddenly get 1k views in an hour, I would like to know if it is just from the Stack Overflow homepage, or from someone's link.

Comment: So you're asking for a list of referrers then, with the unique aspect of your request being that you want a source-by-source breakout of how many visitors have arrived via that link?

Comment: @Shog9 I guess, if that means knowing where they came from being chat, another question, or an external website, etc...