# Count number of visits of a question link posted in facebook if we post it after creating a short url

Tags: support, hyperlinks, publicity-badges

Does Stack Overflow calculate the number of visits if we share a Stack Overflow question link after creating its short URL using Tiny URL?

For example, http://tinyurl.com/3tfrs5m is a link to a question page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it does. The URL is expanded by tinyURL before hits Stack Exchange servers.

Comment: Thanks, to avoid awkwardness, I use to convert long links to short url before posting in facebook. I was wondering whether it counts or not. :)

Comment: @Deepu, opinions about "awkwardness" differ. I, for example, dislike such short links a lot, as I cannot ([easily](http://tinyurl.com/preview.php?num=3tfrs5m)) tell where it's linking to. That aside: note that the "link" link underneath a question is a short link too: `http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96463/164335` (being a [referral](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74274/privacy-leak-in-permalink) to your account) or `http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96463`. For your example, `http://stackoverflow.com/q/6351642` would suffice, and make it very clear it's linking to SO.

Comment: +1 to what @Arjan says.

Comment: +1 to @Arjan, short links are bad.