# Any plans supporting Google+ for link sharing in the near future?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, google-plus

Are there any plans to also support [Google+](http://plus.google.com/) for sharing links to questions, like it is already implemented for Facebook, Twitter and LinkedIn? It has already been opened for public, and seems to be steadily growing.

Comment: I would guess this falls under the beta browser rule - when it's fully released it will be (possibly) supported.

Comment: @ChrisF: It just be fully released soon (few weeks?). I know it doesn't make sense to add it beforehand, but I'm asking if it is planned. Shouldn't be very difficult. The interface should be already public.

Comment: Don't get me wrong - I'm not against the idea, but you might be premature. Also it took a while for Jeff to be persuaded of the value of the LinkedIn link.

Comment: @ChrisF: I'm on LinkedIn which is good for professional contacts, but I was surprised after it got added here.

Comment: So I guess everyone is betting that Google will be successful on the social networking front this time around? Third time's the charm, I suppose.

Comment: This could just be enabled for people that are logged in var google.

Comment: @ChrisF: There was Google Buzz but what was the other attempt?

Comment: Martin - it was @Cody who made the "third time's the charm" comment, but I'm guessing he meant Google Wave.

Comment: @ChrisF: Sorry, the common leading `C` apparently made me look in the wrong line. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Buzz, Wave, and [Orkut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orkut) are all possibilities.

Comment: I would suggest `addthis`. It supports over 300 services and it already has `+1` button.

Comment: I've already added +1 links to some of my pages, so no, it's not hard to do.

Comment: Is +1 the same as "share this"?

Comment: @Martin, More or less -- [Here's a description](http://www.google.com/support/+/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=1364508&answer=1199050&rd=1)

Comment: Why so many google +1 for this question (currently only 2)?

Comment: Personally, I hate the Google +1 button.

Comment: Personally, I love the Google +1 button.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

We have implemented Google+ share links on Stack Overflow and will be rolling these out to the rest of the network very soon.

Comment: Is this a feature of G+ that only `stackOverflow` can use? because I was trying to setup my links like `<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3a%2f%2fmyurl.com" > my g link  </a>` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Mr_Nizzle the G+ implementation is in a preview state right now and we have been whitelisted while the bugs are sorted out

Answer (score 56):

As Arjan noted, we're not inclined to support this until Google+ produces a standard, simple hyperlink way of sharing, the same as our current Twitter and Facebook sharing links. We don't want to slow down every page with third party requests and weird `<iframe>` techniques.

There is no such method at this time, but I have been in contact with Google about this matter, and they are aware of our request.

edit: they have a simple link sharing method now, but it's only for whitelisted providers. We are whitelisted for the time being.

Comment: that's such an annoying, typical corporation answer: "we are **aware** of your request.**"

Comment: @sys.stderr They are still in beta. (Though they should come out of beta this year, IIRC.)

Answer (score 26):

As for now you can:

1. [Search your question on Google and click `+1`](http://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&=&q=https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97406/any-plans-supporting-google-for-link-sharing-in-the-near-future&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1)
2. Post the [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97406/147423) on Google Plus manually
3. Execute the following script then press the `+1` button next to the question title

Code:

```
javascript:var d=$("<span/>").html('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script><g:plusone></g:plusone>');d.appendTo($("#question-header h1"));void(0);
```

If you are using Firefox you can make a script for [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) or [an addon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/building_an_extension). On [Chrome you can make a simple extension](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html) to add that automatically.

I would like to see an [**addthis** button](http://www.addthis.com/), it supports **over 300 services** and it has the Google +1 button.

---

If you are on Firefox you can try this addon: **[+1 Any](http://goo.gl/1FiKv)**

[image: right click to toggle count]

Comment: thanks for mentioning **addthis**. I've just replaced my last chrome extension now!

Comment: also, I've just pulled off a **greasemonkey script** from your snippet, Bruno, that can be very simply installed both on chrome (where no extension is needed) and firefox (where you need the greasemonkey plugin). Hope you enjoy: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/108498

Comment: @Cawas nice script :) Thanks for sharing. I made just one change, I like a smaller button: `<g:plusone size="small">`

Comment: Note that marking a site as "+1" does not share it with your stream! It just adds the site to the "+1" tab at your Google+ profile.

Answer (score 23):

So [a standard, simple hyperlink way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97406/any-plans-supporting-google-for-link-sharing-in-the-near-future/106563#106563) of sharing to Google+ is now making [the rounds on blogs](http://www.howtonew.com/how-to-post-from-google-reader-to-google) (couldn't find an official source, so it may still be undocumented):

```
https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?hl=en&url=%URL
```

Replace `%URL` with the URL. This is what shows up in the Google+ stream:

> [image: Google+ URL post]

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use it in production until there's some official  documentation of it.

Answer (score 8):

Despite [the referral](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74274/privacy-leak-in-permalink) in the URLs, I very much appreciate the current implementation on SE for Facebook, Twitter and LinkedIn. These are plain links, like:

```html
Know someone who can answer? Share a
<a href="/q/97406/...">link</a> to this question via
<a href="mailto:?subject=Stack%20Overflow...&amp;body=...">email</a>,
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=...&amp;text=...">twitter</a>, 
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=...">facebook</a>, or
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?...">linkedin</a>
```

...rather than a (dynamically generated) `<iframe>` or `<img>` that allows for tracking, like:

```html
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=...">
<iframe src="https://plusone.google.com?...">
```

Google states [it's not using the button for tracking](http://www.google.com/support/+/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=1364508&answer=1319578). Still, when adding +1, please add it without any `<iframe>` or web bug too! Google itself [does not](http://code.google.com/apis/+1button/) seem to support this (yet?). [AddThis Share Forward](http://www.addthis.com/help/sharing-api#services_forward), like used on Area 51, [does](http://www.addthis.com/services/list) list `google_plusone`, but that [might not be working yet](http://api.addthis.com/oexchange/0.8/forward/google_plusone/offer?url=http://addthis.com).

I've no idea what the user experience would be like. It surely implies one can then *not* see how many others have liked/[+1'd](http://www.google.com/support/profiles/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=1207011&answer=1237207&rd=1) the page.

Comment: `+1 button` cannot be added without iframe. It will generate one for itself and use html5 `postMessage` to do stuff. And are you saying `iframes` are web bugs? GMail has `5` and Google+ has `7`, in my view (it might be different for different users). `document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").length`...

Comment: @Bruno, if +1 does not offer other APIs, then your nice bookmarklet at least shows that the iframe doesn't have to be on the page *all the time*. (It could be added when someone wants to +1 something, though that's not very user friendly.) As for the possible web bug nature of iframes, [for example](http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424052748704281504576329441432995616.html): *These so-called social widgets [..] notify Facebook and Twitter that a person visited those sites even when users don't click on the buttons, according to a study done for The Wall Street Journal.*

Comment: The web bug discussion is pointless because Stackoverflow started years ago to use a Google web bug.

Comment: @Hendrik, good point... (Though blocking Analytics does not keep one from using some features whenever specifically wanted. But I guess people who're blocking Analytics won't be using +1 either.)

Comment: How could I not think about this... I just setup [Google Chrome +1 Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jgoepmocgafhnchmokaimcmlojpnlkhp) . It's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this was implemented (on Stack Overflow, at least).

> [image: Share buttons]