# Google+ link in "Help us grow this site"

Tags: feature-request, beta-sites, google-plus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any plans supporting Google+ for link sharing in the near future?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97406/any-plans-supporting-google-for-link-sharing-in-the-near-future)

Please can we get a link to share via Google+ in the "Help us grow this site" box on the beta sites?  Also that box should appear more frequently on the beta sites, since promotion is imperative to their success.

I have gone to the lengths of manually sharing the Healthcare IT site via Google+ by the way.  There is a huge Healthcare IT community out there waiting to be brought in from the cold!

Related questions:
[How can we promote our community?](https://sqa.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137/how-can-we-promote-our-community)
[Google +1 for questions](https://sqa.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136/google-1-for-questions)

Comment: Not _quite_ a dupe; that's for regular posts, whereas this is for entire beta sites.