# Does Stack Overflow plan to add "Share to Google+" functionality?

Tags: feature-request, social-networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any plans supporting Google+ for link sharing in the near future?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97406/any-plans-supporting-google-for-link-sharing-in-the-near-future)

I would really like to share some of the Stack Overflow questions/answers on Google+ to share with my friends some interesting materials.

Is that in any plan in Stack Overflow's roadmap?

Comment: Until such time, there are several browser extensions and bookmarklets that make it easy to share any webpage to G+.