# Why do "share" links include user IDs?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, sharing, share-this

I've noticed that the "share" links on answers and comments note that they not only include the answer ID, but the user's ID as well:

[image: screenshot]

Why does Stack Exchange do this? Obviously, it is tracking it, but for what purpose? Does this affect the user?

Comment: +1 for totally confusing me by your screenshot. :D

Comment: I feel there should be a switch or option for this, as some people are more conscious of privacy, and not wanting to be tracked, rather than badges or incentives. At least Stack Exchange tells us about the embedded ID.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

They include your id so you can earn the [Announcer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/74/announcer), [Booster](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/75/booster) and [Publicist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/76/publicist) badges:

> https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges

as far as I know that's the only use of the user id in the link.

Answer (score 9):

You get a [badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges) for it. Who doesn't like incentives?

The three badges are [Announcer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/74/announcer) (bronze), [Booster](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/75/booster) (silver), and [Publicist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/76/publicist) (gold).

Comment: “Who doesn't like incentives?“ people who do not want their id to be tracked without their consent https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74274/privacy-leak-in-permalink