# Why does the URL to an answer include the question ID?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, architecture

On Stack Overflow the link to an answer looks like this

```
https://stackoverflow.com/a/<answer-id>/<question-id>
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/69119825/819887
```

Out of curiosity:

- Why was this format chosen (instead of just `https://stackoverflow.com/a/<answer-id>/`)
- Are there any speed gains to include both ids (`<question-id>` and `<answer-id>`)?
- Is there an article that explains why this URL scheme was used?

Comment: Weakly related: [Why did the format of full-form URLs to answers change?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313428) and [Why do Stack Exchange URLs expand to include an additional fragment to the route?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367202)

Comment: I think the boring answer will be because of SEO.

Comment: Isn't there a canonical question for this? This can't be the first time. Some candidates and related: *[For what purposes is my user id used when sharing a link?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113638/)*, *[Why do "share" links include user IDs?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292127/)*, *[Anonymize or hash the user ID part of a shared link so users can earn badges for sharing links without any privacy leaks or prank/troll risks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340346/)*, and —

Comment: cont' — *[Privacy leak in permalink?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74274/)*,

Comment: Related: *[Documentation for Stack Exchange engine URLs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332237/documentation-for-stack-exchange-engine-urls/332251#332251)*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It doesn't. `819887` is a user ID, to be precise the one who clicked on the 'Share' link underneath the answer. You can see it in your profile as well: `https://stackoverflow.com/users/819887/surfmuggle`. This is to keep track of referrals for the [Announcer badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/74/announcer) and family.

Now, when you visit that link, you'll see that the final URL does contain both the question and answer ID:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69119268/how-do-i-roll-to-a-specific-browser-version-with-playwright/69119825#69119825
```

`69119268` is the question ID, that's the canonical URL for SEO purposes. The answer ID `69119825` appears *twice*: once to make sure that you're on the right page if there are lots of answers; the #69119825 is the slug which makes your browser scroll to that answer.

You might be interested in [Documentation for Stack Exchange engine URLs?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332237/295232) and [List of unlinked pages on Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76566/295232) to learn more.

Comment: To be fair, the expanded answer link _does_ contain both IDs, but that makes a little more sense with the question ID coming first: `https://$site/questions/<Question-ID>/<Question-Title-Kebab-Case>/<Answer-ID>`

Comment: I hate links that contain useless titles in their path. I always strip them off when sharing them.