# Share questions without automatically showing own account ID

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, share-this

When I click "Share" on a question or an answer, if I am logged in, a `/{$account_id}` is automatically appended to the link, probably for the [Announcer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/74/announcer) family of badges <sup>[citation needed]</sup>. However, this account ID can be easily used for resolving the account name and other public details, simply through `https://domain.stackexchange.com/users/{$account_id}`.

This may lead to users accidentally leaking their account when they share the links. As far as I understand from a quick google on "StackExchange real name policy" and "StackExchange multiple accounts policies", StackExchange does not have any explicit stances on anonymity or having multiple virtual online identities, but this problem may accidentally make other people know about your StackExchange account as another virtual identity.

As a matter of fact, I only have one SE account, and as you can see, it is obviously anonymous from real life. Just now, I almost included my account name when sending it to a friend who doesn't know about this identity of mine.

Here I am suggesting three possible solutions:

1. In account settings, set the preference not to include the account ID, but instead, like a non-logged-in visitor. This may, however, lead to the Announcer-family badges not working.
2. Make a separate table (or whatever) in the database that maps numbers to question/answer IDs + user ID, so when a user clicks "share", a random/increment number is generated and mapped to the user's ID and question/answer ID.
3. Simply encrypt the user ID with an internal key, then with the question/answer ID, i.e.:

```
share_link = 'https://domain.stackexchange.com/q/' + question_id + '/' + encrypt(
    key: question_id,
    message: encrypt(
        key: internal_key,
        message: user_id
    )
)
```

Comment: ... or you just delete the ID from the end of the link entirely before you share it.

Comment: You could use [this userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/6507/41053) (and notice my user ID is in that link; I don't use that script ;)

Comment: If you are so worried about privacy, then open post before sharing in private mode in browser. In this case link doesn't contain your id at all.

Comment: Ever considered what happens with the SE app?

Comment: @Catija If you read my question carefully, the whole thing I am talking about is **accidentally**. Anyone with a working brain can deduce that the ID can be deleted, and even if not, can just be changed to anything.

Comment: You need to open post in private mode **even** if you already in private mode. We need to go deeper :)

Comment: @alexolut nice idea. https://superuser.com/q/835213/542586 :P

Answer (score 1):

The reason the user number is included is so SE can count references toward the Announcer badge family.  Without the user number SE has no idea whom to credit with link referrals, so if you want the badges you have to use it.

But otherwise it's totally optional -- just delete it and the slash that comes before it.  If you find yourself doing this a lot, you can use [SOUP, the Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) to make this easier.  The share link was [recently modified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290920/162102) to add this:

[image: share links (user ID and anonymous)]

Comment: I have never seen that. Are you sure that isn't a userscript?

Comment: This probably does not solve the problem that I still want the Announcer badge :P

Comment: I didn't get this on any of the four sites I tried it on.

Comment: [SOUP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290920/307988)?

Comment: @zondo whoa.  That showed up recently for me and I just assumed it was SE, because I'm not used to SOUP adding new features like that.  (It's more about making things easier.) . Thanks; I'll update the answer.